# Creating a query that uses many to many tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, many-to-many

I have database of a library that contains academic papers. Papers may have multiple co-authors and that information is kept in a many-to-many table since I also have a table of authors. The co-author table is like:

```
Paper ID    Co-author ID
Paper_1     Author_2
Paper_1     Author_5
Paper_1     Author_7
Paper_3     Author_5
...
```

I need to create a query that returns all information about a specific paper including co-authors of it. When I try to do that, I come up with a table like this:

```
Paper ID  Paper Name  Publication Date  Co-author ...
Paper_1   asd         2013              Author_2
Paper_1   asd         2013              Author_5
Paper_1   asd         2013              Author_7
```

I don't want this repeating. I also need to show the citation information of the paper, which is also contained in a many-to-many table like authors and with those 2, the table returns the same information 12 times when the paper has 3 co-authors and 4 citations. How can I manage that? A table like that would be helpful:

```
Paper ID  Paper Name  Publication Date  Co-author  Cited by
Paper_1   asd         2013              Author_2   Paper_15
                                        Author_5   Paper_22
                                        Author_7   Paper_23
                                                   Paper_25
```

or if you have a better idea for the table design, I'm open to those. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: if you don't want to repeat information, and say you have a record that says Author_7,  I wonder how would you be able to tell to what paper it belongs?. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should do this type of formatting in the application.  The result set you want is highly dependent on the ordering of the rows -- and, ironically, does not have information in the rows to express that ordering

Comment: Your desired result is not a table! Tables are rectangular sets of data - having a row that only contains `Paper_25` makes not sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you keep the initial result you have...

```
Paper ID  Paper Name  Publication Date  Co-author ...
Paper_1   asd         2013              Author_2
Paper_1   asd         2013              Author_5
Paper_1   asd         2013              Author_7
```

If you examine the above, each row has a `Paper ID` as an identifier. The result you desire is actually incomplete data, what you are actually asking for is NULL data that will be incomplete for the viewer.

```
Paper ID  Paper Name  Publication Date  Co-author  Cited by
Paper_1   asd         2013              Author_2   Paper_15
NULL      NULL        NULL              Author_5   Paper_22
NULL      NULL        NULL              Author_7   Paper_23
NULL      NULL        NULL              NULL       Paper_25
```

Looking at your desired result, for Paper_25 there is technically no data related to that `Cited By` row making it redundant. The SQL language isn't exactly built for styling purposes, you are better off leaving such formatting for a spreadsheet program or website style sheets.